# Vue sometimes loads too late(?) in my Laravel + Bootstrap 4 application

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I just upgraded Bootstrap on a Laravel 7 application from 3.x to 4.5.0 and I'm running Vue 2.6.11, but the upgrade introduced strange behaviour.

I see unparsed Vue code in the browser. The page then reloads, a fraction of a second later, to show the correctly parsed page. This is what it looks like when it goes wrong:
[image]

The network tab doesn't show any differences between a regular load (without seeing Vue code) and a failed one (where I do see Vue code). There're no errors in the console either, and nothing much has changed between our Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 setup.

The behaviour happens rarely on Chrome, but almost always on IE11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `v-cloak`. It will hide all of your vue content until Vue is fully rendered, then Vue will remove the attribute. Use it like so:

```
    <div id="my-vue-app" v-cloak>
    </div>
```

And in your styles, you will need:

```
    [v-cloak] { display:none; }
```

Comment: Wow, this seems to work. Do you know why this wasn't necessary in earlier versions of either Vue or Bootstrap?

Comment: It has always been "necessary", it is just about how long your code takes to be fully initialized. v-cloak has been around for a long time, to solve this issue. The reason you are needing it now, is there is something in your js/vue that is taking a long time for Vue to be in the mounted state (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).